# How to force my project to use newer node 14.x?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

My application is launched by either `npm start` or `yarn start` which defined as:
`"start": "node scripts/start.js"` which leads to some boilerplate script to start stuff.

Failed to compile.

```
./src/components/Something/Something.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (8:16)

   6 | function testOptionalChaining(id, items) {
   7 |   return filter(items,(item) => {
>  8 |     return item?.id == id
     |                 ^
   9 | })
```

My local has nvm manager installed, with several installed but `v14.19.3` the one in use, also confirmed with

```
❯ npm --version
6.14.17
❯ node -v
v14.19.3
```

I have done some reading, and tried adding in my `composer.json`:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.5.0"
  },
```

As well as `.npmrc` file with `engine-strict=true`

Followed by removal of `node_modules` and `npm install`

However the compiling error is still there, I've also tested by updating our `Dockerfile` to `FROM node:14-slim AS node` and letting our CI build it with the above modifications, just on the off chance its something local - but the build pipeline returns the same error.

Update:
I've tried again today using another laptop - same issue, but this time I printed out the Node version:
`console.log(chalk.green('Node version: ' + process.version + '\n'));`
And that comes as `Node version: v14.21.3`, yet still resulting in the same error..

I am at a loss what else to try, I really want the optional chaining available to me!

Comment: Have you tried using NVM (node verison manager) to install your specific version of node?

Comment: wait, isn't this is just a syntax error ?

Comment: `return id === item?.id ?? ""`
can you do this ?

Comment: @DanteDX No its not just an error, I want this functionality: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#specifications Its supposed to be supported in Node 14.x according to node.green website

Comment: @DustinSpengler what is my specific node version? Like I've said, I do use NVM, and I do currently have 14.9.3 selected - its not working as outlined above

Comment: @DanteDX I tried your suggestion using null coalescing above, still returns the same error

Comment: ensure that your project is using the correct version of Node.js, you can try setting the Node.js version in your project's package.json

Comment: @KareemAdel Please specify how, because I tried setting using engine, and read my update I actually console logged the used node version - apparently its using the correct version but the compiling error above is still present